# Will any effect to RAM if we increase open_files_limit for mysql Database

Tags: mysql

- I wanted to increase open_files_limit = 10000 to avoid  "Out of
  resources error in mysql"
- My question is if we increase open_files_limit value will it affect RAM

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18036/mysql-how-do-you-determine-the-ideal-open-files-limit-setting-value

Comment: @Mihai, the link which you given tells regarding how to correct value for open_files_limit...but i want to know increase open_files_limit value will create any issue with RAM/Memory or performance

Comment: Before you "solve" your question, is the issue that you have related to MySQL's setting `file_per_table`?

Comment: @N.B. it is related to mysql open_files_limit configuration

Comment: I read that part, but what I'm asking whether you also have `file_per_table` which causes you to hit `open_files_limit`.  Raising that limit is a soft setting, there's also hard one controlled by the OS. What happens really is that you are mostly going to waste CPU power rather than RAM. FDs don't consume that much memory. So again - have you got `file_per_table` set to 1 maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it will affect the memory.

Obviously, 1000 files opened will spend more memory than 500.

Is really necessary to change that limit? perhaps some improvements on your application will avoid that change